# Android and formatting text with html

Tags: android, html, textview, string-formatting

This may be an elementary question for some but I've been looking at this for the past couple of hours. In the string below, the newlines don't appear and the font-size doesn't change. The newline seems like it should work with no problem but it's not:

```
String tempStr = "<font color='blue'>" + mUserName + " </font>" + "<font color='black'>" + " \"" + some.toString() + "\" " + "</font>" + "<font size=6>" + timespan + "</font>";

result.setText(Html.fromHtml(tempStr) + "\n\n\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newlines in HTML should be `<br>, <p> or even <div`> ? I would suggest using inline CSS styles instead. I have not tried that with fromHtml, but it should work?

Comment: The <font size=6> markup works OK on Android when tested the simple way, with a static HTML document without CSS. I’d suggest that you test with the HTML generated, saved on a static page, and post the URL for analysis (and run HTML validation too). In an environment with style sheets in use, the <font size=6> markup may be ignored because it is overrun by CSS settings